# 90s (or earlier) Japanese anime movie: two planets at war, young man is in love with princess from the other planet, and floods his own village

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I would like to find out the title of a Japanese anime feature film (not a series) that I saw on Romanian TV in the early 90s.

It was about a feud between the peoples of two planets (one very technologically advanced, the other not). The two planets go to war against each other, and a young man from one of the planets falls in love with a princess from the other planet.

I recall a scene where the army of the second planet take off in hot air balloons when they go to war.

The only other thing I recall is that there is a dam next to the village where the young man lives, and for some reason he opens the dam gates and floods his own village.

I do not recall there being robots in the movie, however I remember very vaguely that the technology level was probably at the level of late 19th century Europe on one planet and pre-industrial on the other one.

What it's not:

- *Nobunaga the Fool*
- *Aldnoah Zero*
- *Queen Millennia*
- *Uchuu Senkan Yamato* (movie)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobunaga_the_Fool?

Comment: @Valorum, I definitely see the similarities, however Nubunaga is not it. The anime I am looking for aired on Romanian TV in the early 90s, perhaps not too long after the fall of the Iron Curtain. I see on Wikipedia that Nobunaga ran in 2014, however the similarities make me wonder if the makers of Nobunaga drew some inspiration from this earlier feature film that I saw about 25 years ago as a kid.

Comment: This seems very similar but very recent; https://myanimelist.net/anime/22729/AldnoahZero

Comment: Interesting, I suppose that the theme has been reused a lot. I do not recall there being robots in the movie, however I remember very vaguely that the technology level was probably at the level of late 19th century Europe on one planet and pre-industrial on the other one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Millennia?

Comment: I don't think this is it.

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/anime/711/Uchuu_Senkan_Yamato_Movie?

Comment: This isn’t it, also it was a standalone feature anime film, not a series.

Comment: @AndreiIrimia Leiji matsumoto has done a lot of series but films too about his own series or as standalone too , if you remember the art style (a trademark of his works) perhaps you want to check his works https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiji_Matsumoto

Comment: @AndreiIrimia if you saw it in the early 90s, there is a good chance that the movie is from the 80s so I recommend you to look for the anime films and anime OVAS categories here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1980s_anime, perhaps it is listed already-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are talking about **[Windaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windaria)** (1986), described below.

> The mountainous kingdom of Paro and the coastal city-state of Itha had been at peace for over a century. They would have remained that way but for the ambitions of Paro's power-hungry king. Paro invaded Itha, despite the love between Jill, Paro's prince, and Ahanas, Itha's princess. Caught between duty and emotion, the star-crossed lovers were forced to fight a war to its bitter conclusion. Isu was a simple farmer from the neutral village of Saki, but he saved Itha from being destroyed by a spy from Paro, and found himself hungering for wealth and glory that the Ithan monarchy could provide. Agents from Paro made him an offer to fulfill his wishes, and he left his wife Marin behind in what would turn into a battlefield between the two kingdoms.

It's not about two planets, but two kingdoms; otherwise, the story is as you described.

[image: Windaria cover, multiple characters]